# Relacionamento n:n no Django com chamada na grid

Tags: python, django, relacionamento, django-templates

Boa noite.

Estou criando um sistema em Python/Django onde tenho um relacionamento n:n entre uma tabela **Pessoa** e outra **Processo** e para isso criei uma terceira entidade chamada **ParteProcessual**.

Fiz os seguintes:

```
class Pessoa(models.Model):
    nome            = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    data_nascimento = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    [...]

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nome


class Processo(models.Model):
    numero              = models.CharField('número', max_length=25)
    prioridade          = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    [...]
    pessoas             = models.ManyToManyField(Pessoa, through='ParteProcessual', related_name='parte_processual_mtm', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.numero


class ParteProcessual(models.Model):
    pessoa = models.ForeignKey(Pessoa, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='pessoa_fk')
    processo = models.ForeignKey(Processo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='processo_fk')
    polo_processual = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=POLO_PROCESSUAL)
    tipo_parte = models.CharField('tipo de parte', max_length=20) #Autor, réu, embargante, impungnante, etc.
    is_cliente = models.BooleanField('cliente')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.pessoa.nome +' - Processo n.º '+ self.processo.numero
```

No Admin está funcionando ok o relacionamento, mas no HTML fiz uma listagem dos processos e estou tentando buscar o nome das pessoas (separadas por vírgula) pelo relacionamento **pessoas** constante no model **Processo** e não estou conseguindo.

No template fiz o seguinte:

```
{% for processo in processos %}
     <tr role="row" class="odd">
         <td class="sorting_1">{{ processo.data_ajuizamento|date:"d/m/Y" }}</td>
         <td>{{ processo.numero }}</td>
         <td>{{ processo.fase_processual }}</td>
         <td>{{ processo.pessoas }}</td>
         <td>{{ processo.status }}</td>
         <td class="p-0"><a href="{% url 'edicao-processo' processo.id %}" class="btn btn-warning"><i class="fas fa-edit"></i></a></td>
         <td class="p-0"><a href="#modalDelete" data-toggle="modal" data-id="{{ processo.id }}" class="modalBtn btn btn-danger" ><i class="fas fa-eraser"></i></a></td>
     </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Na listagem está aparecendo o seguinte erro: **pessoas.Pessoa.None**. Alguém sabe a solução?

Answer (score 1):

Olá, você deve fazer uma iteração no atributo `pessoas`. Algo como, `{% for pessoa in processo.pessoas.all %}`. Então dentro de cada objeto da iteração você vai poder acessar os atributos da classe `Pessoa`. Agora, se você quer acessar os atributos da classe `ParteProcessual` você deve fazer da seguinte forma: `{% for obj in processo.processo_fk.all %}`, a partir de `obj` você pode acessar os atributos `polo_processual`, `tipo_parte` e `is_cliente`.

Comment: Obrigado, amigo. Depois de muito quebrar a cabeça eu havida conseguido justamente desta forma que você explicou.